# Matlab draw line in image using line equation

Tags: matlab

Given two coordinate points A and B and its gradient 'slopes'. Now, I want to draw a line (with `linspace` - function) on an image which worked for lines with a gradient ~1. The line stopped at the image boundary (due to xlims and ylims).

```
imshow(I)
xlims = xlim(gca);
ylims = ylim(gca);
```

Now the problem: I try to repeat for another line which is nearly vertical and it did not stop at the image boundary (see picture):

[image: Image here]

Any solutions how I can draw a line using a y=mx+c equation that stops at the image boundary independent from the gradient?

EDIT:

```
img = uint8(zeros(382, 382));

pointA = [181.4594, 129.7092];
pointB = [185.3411, 251.6005];

imshow(img)
hold on
plot(pointA(1), pointA(2), 'ro')
plot(pointB(1), pointB(2), 'bo')
hold off

% From y = mx + x
slope = 31.4015;
intercept = -5.5684e+03;


xlims = xlim(gca);
ylims = ylim(gca);

y = xlims*slope + intercept;


Xline = linspace(xlims(1), xlims(2), 382);
Xline_pole1 = linspace(xlims(1), pointA(1), 382/2);
Xline_pole2 = linspace(xlims(2), pointB(1), 382/2);
Yline = Xline*slope + intercept;
Yline_pole1 = Xline_pole1*slope + intercept;
Yline_pole2 = Xline_pole2*slope + intercept;

hold on
plot( Xline_pole1, Yline_pole1, 'Color', 'b', 'LineWidth', 3 );
hold off


% Check how many coordinates are within image frame
for zz=1:length(Xline_pole1)
    hold on
    plot(Xline_pole1(zz),Yline_pole1(zz), 'm+');
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you currently have for making the plot?

Comment: Short answer: compute the linspace in a way that respects the bounds of the image up front, and your lims shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I created a toy example: Please see the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround:
Just reset your limits after you plotted your lines

```
imshow(I) 
xlims = xlim(gca);
ylims = ylim(gca);
% plot your lines
xlim(xlims)
ylim(ylims)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Please see the toy example I attached to the first post.